# Front Panel MIcrophone Noise Spike

Tags: microphone, noise

I'm experiencing noise on my microphone which is connected to the computer's front panel audio ports. It's a brand new PC. The rear audio ports work just fine. The front Headphone port works well and the only issue comes from the microphone port.

The reason I call it a noise spike is because it happens when I open heavy programs like Adobe Premiere Pro or games or when there's load on my PC in any way.

What could be causing the problem? My motherboard is Asus H610M-K DDR4 if that helps